# Unlocking the ethereum account in azure using azure cloud shell

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, metamask, azure

I have created an ethereum account in azure using ethereum consortium proof of concept and linking  metamask with it ,I m trying to unlock the adrees of ethereum i have created 
[image][image]
I HAVE TRIED IN BOTH WAYS AND both ways leads to error i want to unlock my ethereum account to use with my website [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQYZA.jpg)

Comment: can you give the command used to run geth?

Comment: Geth attach http://ethcyy5j4-dns—reg1-eastus-cloudapp.azure.com:8545

Comment: Its an url i took from ethereum i created rpc endpoint url

Comment: you should add this when running geth --rpcapi eth,web3,net,personal

Comment: Adding this too gives me error can i get ur mail address so tht i cld contact you

Comment: geth —rpcapi command not found

Comment: If i give geth —rpcapi “eth,net,web3,personal” it si keep on loading like looking for peers

Comment: Open SSH console for transaction node.
Use an editor to open the "start-private-blockchain.sh"
Add  "--rpcapi "eth,web3,personal""
restart vm

Comment: Unlock account is a bad idea even if noone has access to your node